# Maintain exact same zoom position when replacing low res image with high res

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview that users can zoom in on. The images are very large (3MBs+) so I download a low res version first, then load the large version when the download is complete.

It's seamless, except if the user has zoomed in.

How can I maintain the exact zoom while I replace the low-res image with the high res one? I basically just want the user to see the image get clearer but not change what they're looking at.

Some example sizes for guidance:

- Low res image: (222,200) with a default zoomed in level (when double tapped): 4.55...
- High res image: (1184,1067) with a default zoomed in level: 0.854...
- The UIScrollview itself is basically full screen with AspectFit (414.0,672.0)

Here's a code sample of where I'm doing a similar thing. Users can also adjust the brightness of an image. In that case I'm swapping out an image with the exact same dimensions so this code works, but not if the dimensions change.

```
// Get the frame & zoom scale of image before replacing it
let tempZoomScale = pageImageViews[pageToUse].zoomScale
let tempFrame = pageImageViews[pageToUse].contentOffset

// Replace the image with the newly formatted one
pageImageViews[pageToUse].display(image: imageToUse)

// Set the same zoom position as it was before we swapped the image
if (maintainZoomPosition == true) {
    pageImageViews[pageToUse].zoomScale = tempZoomScale
    pageImageViews[pageToUse].contentOffset = tempFrame
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you replacing the zoomed view itself???

Comment: Yes, I'm using the ImageScrollView library [source](https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView) which has a displayImage method that adds the ImageView as a subview.

Comment: OK but don't do that. If you simply replace the old _image_ with the old _image_ inside the image view, it will be shown the same way. If you replace the zoomable view, you've really messed things up, because you've lost the connection between the scroll view's idea of how things are zoomed and the transform / offset applied to the zoomable view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I maintain the exact zoom while I replace the low-res image with the high res one?

Just do it — replace the low-res image with the high-res image. But do not replace the image *view* containing the image; that seems to be your mistake here. Doing that is tantamount to interfering with the scroll view's entire zoom mechanism, which is what's causing your issues.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the guidance. Took some refactoring to update the library I was using to either create a ImageView if one didn't exist, and simply update the image if there already was one in place. Works like a charm now! 

Answer (score 1):

If you put the images inside of a UIImageView with its content mode set to `.scaleAspectFit`, and that image view has a set size, then replacing the image with one of a higher resolution shouldn't change zoom level at all.

Answer (score 0):

The work you want to do isn't good from the point of performance.
The better way is to show some progress view until the large image being downloaded, then replace the image and remove progress view.